# When to use Observable.FromEventPattern rather than Observable.FromEvent?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

We've got a client calling off to a TIBCO EMS queue and are wiring up the events like this:

```
var msgConsumer = _session.CreateConsumer(responseQueue);
var response = Observable
    .FromEvent<EMSMessageHandler, EMSMessageEventArgs> (
        h => msgConsumer.MessageHandler += h,
        h => msgConsumer.MessageHandler -= h)
    .Where(arg => arg.Message.CorrelationID == message.MessageID);
```

When I call `response.Subscribe(...)` I get  System.ArgumentException "Error binding to target method."

I can make it work with `Observable.FromEventPattern<EMSMessageEventArgs>(msgConsumer, "MessageHandler")` but then it's got the event as a string and just not as clean.

Also I have `IObservable<EventPattern<EMSMessageEventArgs>>` rather than `IObservable<EMSMessageEventArgs>`

What I'd like to understand is: when should I use `FromEvent` over `FromEventPattern`? It seems a bit trial and error.

Comment: There are other overloads of FromEventPattern which do not have a string parameter if that's what you are concerned about.

Comment: Thanks, I'd missed that overload. Yes the string did bother me, but it was more the difference between my FromEvent and FromEventPattern (see comment on your answer below)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895373/how-to-use-observable-fromevent-instead-of-fromeventpattern-and-avoid-string-lit for a full explanation of FromEvent too.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

"Use FromEvent for events structurally don't look like a .NET event pattern (i.e. not based on sender, event args), and use FromEventPattern for the pattern-based ones." - [Bart De Smet (Rx team)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/rx/thread/5f4df41c-6df1-42be-b7bb-bbf072143c24)

Comment: Thanks, I had found that comment but I think I misunderstood what it meant. Would it be correct to say? The .NET event pattern has a signature of delegate void Handler(object sender, EventArgs args) if the event matched that use FromEventPattern (more verbose but, perhaps a littler clearer)

Answer (score 23):

To elaborate on this a bit further, you can typically determine when to choose one of the `FromEvent` vs `FromEventPattern` by the type of event used in the class you're trying to observe. Use [`FromEventPattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) when your event is of type `EventHandler` or the generic `EventHandler<T>`. Use [`FromEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromevent%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) when you're using a custom, non-generic event handler type.
The following examples are lifted directly from the [Rx wiki](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/), which has lots of good examples- [101 of them](http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples) to be exact.

**FromEventPattern** (with generic EventHandler)**:**

```
class ObserveEvent_Generic
{
    public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs { }
    public static event EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> GenericEvent;

    static void Main()
    {
        // To consume GenericEvent as an IObservable:
        IObservable<EventPattern<SomeEventArgs>> eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<SomeEventArgs>(
            ev => GenericEvent += ev,
            ev => GenericEvent -= ev );
    }
}
```

**FromEvent:**

```
class ObserveEvent_NonGeneric
{
    public class SomeEventArgs : EventArgs { }
    public delegate void SomeNonGenericEventHandler(object sender, SomeEventArgs e);
    public static event SomeNonGenericEventHandler NonGenericEvent;

    static void Main()
    {
        // To consume NonGenericEvent as an IObservable, first inspect the type of EventArgs used in the second parameter of the delegate.
        // In this case, it is SomeEventArgs.  Then, use as shown below.
        IObservable<IEvent<SomeEventArgs>> eventAsObservable = Observable.FromEvent(
            (EventHandler<SomeEventArgs> ev) => new SomeNonGenericEventHandler(ev), 
            ev => NonGenericEvent += ev,
            ev => NonGenericEvent -= ev);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Apparently the new syntax has changed a bit. The current syntax is the following:

```cs
// get events as observable 
var events = Observable.FromEvent<MouseButtonEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
    handler => MouseUp += handler, handler => MouseUp -= handler);

// subscribe to events
var subscription = events.Subscribe(args => OnMouseUp()));

// always dispose subscriptions! 
subscription.Dispose();
```